# Polling check Readiness of a Pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud, microservices

I'm searching to an advice to implement this scenario. On my k8s namespace I have X different pods and during some stress/stability test what that I want is to monitoring the restarts of the pods and collect the instant when this happens and the relative pod incriminated.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to implement it? To do this I would like to use a script or python or shell.
Thanks every one!

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192712/kubernetes-watch-pod-events-with-api

Answer (score 0):

There could be many possible implementations of what you are trying to achieve.

**One of the ways** you could do it is by using:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes client: Python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)*

An example of a Python script that will watch for the `Pods` in a specific `namespace` is following:

> **IMPORTANT!**
>
> Please consider this code as an example and not production ready!

```py
import os
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
import datetime 

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

stream = watch.Watch().stream(v1.list_namespaced_pod, "default")

for pod in stream:
    
    print("Pod: %s, Time: %s Event: %s" % (pod['object'].metadata.name, datetime.datetime.now(), pod['type']))
    
    if pod['type'] == "DELETED": 
        print("Hey, your Pod was DELETED. Check it out!")
```

Consider above piece of code as a baseline which you can improve upon and set to your specific use case (specific status, readiness etc.).

> A side note!
>
> You can use `pod['object']` to print whole resource which you can inspect and create conditions upon.

---

#### Example

Above piece of code will work in following way (assuming that your Python code is already running):

- `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`
- `$ kubectl delete deployment nginx`

Output of the `Python` code:

```sh
Pod: nginx-6799fc88d8-6xwrf, Time: 2021-05-28 12:22:47.093388 Event: ADDED
Pod: nginx-6799fc88d8-6xwrf, Time: 2021-05-28 12:22:47.101510 Event: MODIFIED
Pod: nginx-6799fc88d8-6xwrf, Time: 2021-05-28 12:22:47.148491 Event: MODIFIED
Pod: nginx-6799fc88d8-6xwrf, Time: 2021-05-28 12:22:48.741335 Event: MODIFIED
Pod: nginx-6799fc88d8-6xwrf, Time: 2021-05-28 12:23:07.524967 Event: MODIFIED
Pod: nginx-6799fc88d8-6xwrf, Time: 2021-05-28 12:23:07.780190 Event: MODIFIED
Pod: nginx-6799fc88d8-6xwrf, Time: 2021-05-28 12:23:08.789947 Event: MODIFIED
Pod: nginx-6799fc88d8-6xwrf, Time: 2021-05-28 12:23:08.806349 Event: DELETED
Hey, your Pod was DELETED. Check it out!
```

---

I encourage you to check other resources for additional reference:

- *[Ianlewis.org: Qucik look on Kubernetes python client](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/quick-look-kubernetes-python-client)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Kubernetes watch pod events with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192712/kubernetes-watch-pod-events-with-api)* - as pointed by Yayotrón

Comment: Hi, I haven't tried it yet. As soon as I put it on I'll let you know  ;)